# Backup BBDD con MariaDB en una aplicación de Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, class

He realizado como trabajo de clase una aplicación muy sencilla en la que nos conectamos a una base de datos con nombre 'Concesionario' y usuario root y password root. Tiene dos tablas, una Propietarios y otra Vehículos.
Ahora tengo que exportar esa aplicación para mandarle a la plataforma el trabajo y que este lo corrija.
Se como exportar a zip el proyecto en Netbeans, eso es fácil. Pero no se hacer lo mismo con la base de datos, no se que archivo le tengo que enviar o como exportar la base de datos con los datos que tiene para que el profesor la pueda importar en su pc y lo pueda ver.
¿Cómo lo podría hacer?
No adjunto código alguno porque la aplicación funciona correctamente y lo que deseo hacer es exportar el archivo que contenga la base de datos que estoy utilizando en la aplicación.

Comment: podrías crear un script de creación de la base de datos y mandarle eso.

Comment: Y no se te ocurrio preguntarle a tu profesor como queria recibir lo que hiciste?

Comment: Por supuesto. Es una plataforma online y no hacen mucho caso. Por no decir que pasan olímpicamente de todo